# Check if a file is valid XML without header in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using Java to call a remote webservice, sometimes it sends me a reply that is a "valid" XML but without header, like this:

```
<Re>
    <Re1>
        <code>108</code>
        <desc>Error.</desc>
        <det>Imposible ejecutar</det>
    </Re1>
</Re>
```

Due to the lack of header I cannot process it, so I'm thinking to add header myself, but before I want to check if it's a valid XML or only garbage.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.edankert.com/validate.html)

Comment: If by "header" you mean the XML declaration, that's optional, and you should be able to process an input document that doesn't have an XML declaration provided the encoding is OK.